# Rectify incomplete year - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a year column in a dataframe that has unique values like

```
['2017', '2018', '2019', '2015', '2016', '2011', '2010', '2014',
 '215', '2013', nan, '216', '217', '2008', '218', '219',
 '2012', '211', '2002', '214', '17']
```

Some years have been incompletely written. For example, 217 represents 2017, 17 represents 2017 etc
Is it possible to replace the values with the correct year without hard coded replacement?

I've searched a bit for any solution myself, but haven't been able to land on anything useful.

Comment: Depends on the definition of valid years and level of incompletion.

Comment: That's true, say 17 could either be like 1917 or 2017. Could we keep a date range of 2000-2099

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

years = ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2015', '2016', '2011', '2010', '2014',
 '215', '2013', np.nan, '216', '217', '2008', '218', '219',
 '2012', '211', '2002', '214', '17']

corrected_years = ["20" + year[-2:] if year is not np.nan else year for year in years]
```

---

*Output:*

> ```
> ['2017',
>  '2018',
>  '2019',
>  '2015',
>  '2016',
>  '2011',
>  '2010',
>  '2014',
>  '2015',
>  '2013',
>  nan,
>  '2016',
>  '2017',
>  '2008',
>  '2018',
>  '2019',
>  '2012',
>  '2011',
>  '2002',
>  '2014',
>  '2017']
> ```